# Bootstrap: two files with same code in same browser different results

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

i have a little big problem with a project in Bootstrap. I have two files with the same code: ctr+a to select all the code from the original file, ctrl+c to copy it then ctrl+v to paste it in the second file.

I'm currently using Bootstrap 3.

The result is this:

[image]

The original file is the one in the bottom half of the image and the copy is the one in the upper half.
Both files are in the same directory. The code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../assets/ico/favicon.png"> -->

    <title>Navbar Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/mainhardt.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="js/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

    <!-- Static navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Associació d'Amics de Mainhardt</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">Inici</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Publicacions <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Revistes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Llibres</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Intercanvi</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Jornades d'Estudis Gaspatxers <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">I Jornades "El Carlisme a les nostres terres"</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">II Jornades "Memòries al voltant d'una guerra"</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">III Jornades "Retalls de cultura popular"</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Gent d'ací <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Carme Vidal</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Jorge Julve</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Mar de fons</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Exposicions <b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Eclipse 1905</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Cara a cara (Carme Vidal & Joan Sanz)</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>

    <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: #E3F6CE;">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="img/LOGO GRANDE.png"/>
    </div>
    <!--  Carousel -->
    <!--  consult Bootstrap docs at
          http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel -->
    <div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <a href="http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/pr2006046a/xlarge_web/npp/128/">
                    <img class="imagen-slider" src="img/slider/desembre2009.jpg" alt="Antennae Galaxies" />
                </a>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>The Antennae Galaxies</p>
                    <p><a href="http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/pr2006046a/xlarge_web/npp/128/">Hubblesite.org &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/pr2007016e/xlarge_web/npp/128/">
                    <img class="imagen-slider" src="img/slider/abril2010.jpg" alt="Carina Caterpillar" />
                </a>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>Carina Nebula: The Caterpillar</p>
                    <p><a href="http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/pr2007016e/xlarge_web/npp/128/">Hubblesite.org &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/pr2003010i/npp/128/">
                    <img class="imagen-slider" src="img/slider/cartelljornadesgaspatxeres2.jpg" alt="Light Echo" />
                </a>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>Light Echo From Star V838 Monocerotis</p>
                    <p><a href="http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/pr2003010i/npp/128/">Hubblesite.org &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/pr2006024a/xlarge_web/npp/128/">
                    <img src="img/ngc5866.jpg" alt="Galaxy NGC5866" />
                </a>
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>Galaxy NGC 5866</p>
                    <p><a href="http://hubblesite.org/gallery/album/entire/pr2006024a/xlarge_web/npp/128/">Hubblesite.org &raquo;</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- .carousel-inner -->
        <!--  next and previous controls here
              href values must reference the id for this carousel -->
        <a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
    </div><!-- .carousel -->
    <!-- end carousel -->
    <div class="separador"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img_small" src="img/Main%20trans.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><h2>Quí som?</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img_small" src="img/Main%20trans.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><h2>Publicacions</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img_small" src="img/Main%20trans.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><h2>Intercanvi</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="separador"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img_small" src="img/Main%20trans.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><h3>Jornades d'estudis Gaspatxers</h3></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img_small" src="img/Main%20trans.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><h2>Gent d'ací</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <img class="img_small" src="img/Main%20trans.png" alt="...">
                <div class="caption">
                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li class="active"><h2>Exposicions</h2></li>
                    </ul>
                    <br>
                    <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="separador_grande"></div>
    <div class="jumbotron" style="background-color: #333333;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-3 contacte">
                <h4>Contacte</h4>
                <p class="contacte_info">
                    <img src="img/contacte.ico">  Associació d'amics de Mainhardt<br>
                    <img src="img/mail.ico"> correu@1and1.es<br>
                    <img src="img/tlf.ico"> tlf contacte<br>
                </p>
            </div>
            <!-- Formulari Contacte
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 contacte">
                    <h2>Formulari de contacte</h2>
                <form role="form">
                    <div class="form-group input-group-sm">
                        <label for="inputEmail1">Direcció e-mail</label>
                        <input  type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="e-mail">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputName">Nom</label>
                        <input  type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Nom">
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="inputText">Missatge</label>
                        <textarea  class="form-control" rows="3" id="inputText" placeholder="Missatge"></textarea>
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Envia</button>
                </form>
            </div>
            Fi Formulari Contacte -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-9 col-lg-9 contacte">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav contacte_info menu_abajo">
                    <li><h4>Inici</h4></li>
                    <li>
                        <h4>Publicacions</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Revistes</li>
                            <li>Llibres</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><h4>Intercanvi</h4></li>
                    <li>
                        <h4>Jornades Gaspatxeres</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>I Jornades</li>
                            <li>II Jornades</li>
                            <li>II Jornades</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h4>Gent d'aci</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Carme Vidal</li>
                            <li>Jorge Julve</li>
                            <li>Mar de fons</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <h4>Exposicions</h4>
                        <ul>
                            <li>Eclipse 1905</li>
                            <li>Cara a Cara</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="separador_grande"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 contacte">
                <p class="contacte_info copyright">Avís legal. Copyright </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->


<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
================================================== -->
<!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel({
            interval: 4000
        });
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

And this is the css with some modifications i made (mainhardt.css)

```
    body
{
    font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(255, 252, 229);
}

.container
{
    background-color: #E3F6CE;
}
p{
    text-align: justify;
}

.img_small
{
    max-height: 100px;
    max-width: 175px;
}

.contacte
{
    color: #999;
}
.contacte_info
{
    font-size: 12px;
}
.copyright
{
    text-align: center;
}

.menu_abajo li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

.menu_abajo > li > ul > li
{
    display: block;
}

.separador
{
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
.separador_grande
{
    margin: 60px 0 60px 0;
}


.carousel-caption {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 10px 15px 5px;
    background: #333333;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

.carousel-caption h4,
.carousel-caption p {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.imagen-slider
{
    margin: 0 auto 0;
}

.carousel-inner
{
    background-image: url(../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png);
}
```

Comment: are you zoomed in or something?

Comment: Press Ctrl + 0 to reset zoom level to 100%.

Comment: Nope, not zoomed. I don't know why but in all the copy files i make, some font sizes are messed up and i can't understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the address bar in the second picture. You have zoomed out in the second picture...

Zooming in will solve your problem..

[image: Updated Screenshot]

Comment: T-T i didn't see that...shame on me. I thought the problem was in the other file. Well...now i only need to adjust it all. Thanks for the help